# Display Some text if is there is no reviews

Tags: magento-1.9, ratings

We are using this code to display **Ratings & Reviews** as below:

[image]

If suppose there is no review for a product, then we want to display text "No rating Available".

```
app/design/frontend/rwd/theme/template/review/product/view/list.phtml

<?php $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();?>
<div class="box-collateral box-reviews" id="customer-reviews">
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
    <div class="review-heading">
        <h2>
            <?php echo $this->__('') ?>
            <span class="reviewtab">
            <?php 
        //  echo count($_items); 
            ?> 
            Ratings & Reviews
            </span>
        </h2>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
    </div>
    <dl>
    <?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>

        <dt>
        <?php $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes(); ?>
            <?php if (count($_votes)): ?>
            <table class="ratings-table">
                <colgroup>

                    <col class="review-value" />
                </colgroup>
                <tbody>

                    <?php foreach ($_votes as $_vote): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                        <td>
                            <div class="rating-box">
                                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewUrl($_review->getId()) ?>">
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_review->getTitle()) ?>
            </a>
        </dt>
        <dd>

            <?php echo nl2br($this->escapeHtml($_review->getDetail())) ?>




            <span class="review-meta">
                <?php echo $this->__('Review by %s', $this->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname())) ?>
                /
               <?php echo $this->__('(Posted on %s)', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') ?>
            </span>
        </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>

    <?php // echo $this->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
<?php elseif($this->getParentBlock()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getParentBlock()->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProduct(), 'short', true)?>
<?php endif;?>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('review_form') ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i check you have already display form for add review in tab so
this tab just need to show review. so please check below code.

```
<?php $_items = $this->getReviewsCollection()->getItems();?>
<div class="box-collateral box-reviews" id="customer-reviews">
<?php if (count($_items)):?>
    <div class="review-heading">
        <h2>
            <?php echo $this->__('') ?>
            <span class="reviewtab">
            <?php 
        //  echo count($_items); 
            ?> 
            Ratings & Reviews
            </span>
        </h2>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('toolbar') ?>
    </div>
    <dl>
    <?php foreach ($_items as $_review):?>

        <dt>
        <?php $_votes = $_review->getRatingVotes(); ?>
            <?php if (count($_votes)): ?>
            <table class="ratings-table">
                <colgroup>

                    <col class="review-value" />
                </colgroup>
                <tbody>

                    <?php foreach ($_votes as $_vote): ?>
                    <tr>
                        <th><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_vote->getRatingCode()) ?></th>
                        <td>
                            <div class="rating-box">
                                <div class="rating" style="width:<?php echo $_vote->getPercent() ?>%;"></div>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <a href="<?php echo $this->getReviewUrl($_review->getId()) ?>">
                <?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_review->getTitle()) ?>
            </a>
        </dt>
        <dd>

            <?php echo nl2br($this->escapeHtml($_review->getDetail())) ?>




            <span class="review-meta">
                <?php echo $this->__('Review by %s', $this->escapeHtml($_review->getNickname())) ?>
                /
               <?php echo $this->__('(Posted on %s)', $this->formatDate($_review->getCreatedAt()), 'long') ?>
            </span>
        </dd>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </dl>
 <?php else: ?>
   <div class="review-heading"><?php echo $this->__('No rating Available'); ?></div>
 <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: hello Baby in Magento as this answerd worked ?

Comment: so please vote as worked.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace:

```
<?php elseif($this->getParentBlock()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->getParentBlock()->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProduct(), 'short', true)?>
<?php endif;?>
```

with:

```
<?php elseif($this->getParentBlock()): ?>
    <?php echo $this->__('No rating Available');?>
    <?php echo $this->getParentBlock()->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProduct(), 'short', true)?>
<?php endif;?>
```

If you also don't want to show **Be the first to review this product**, then comment out:

```
<?php echo $this->getParentBlock()->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProduct(), 'short', true)?>
```

Comment: sorry, that didt worked for me, can you check [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/golden-waves-marble-texture-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html) under `Reviews` section.

Comment: Since you have called review form in another tab, you don't need to write this line:

<?php echo $this->getParentBlock()->getReviewsSummaryHtml($this->getProduct(), 'short', true)?>

You can remove it.

Comment: I have checked it in rwd theme and it is working fine here.

Comment: I removed that line

Comment: Please try to check in rwd theme first and if it still not works, then I can think of any other possibility.

Comment: Glad to know that I could help. :)

Comment: okay..  sure.. :)